# Print function not working at all inside property setter and getter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties, getter-setter

I am trying to create a class that prints whenever a value is changed or got. The problem that I have is that the `print()` statements that I have in the getters and setters don't work, as in they don't print anything to the console.

I also tried to use the `@property` decorator to no avail.

Here is my code:

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, initial_value):
        self._value = initial_value

    def set_value(self, value):
        print(f"Setted value to: {self._value}") # Doesn't get printed at all
        self._value = value

    def get_value(self):
        print(f"Current value is: {self._value}") # Doesn't get printed at all
        return self._value
    
    value = property(set_value, get_value)

instance = SomeClass(0)
instance.value = 50
print(instance.value) # 50
```

EDIT: I've found the issue being that I tried to use the wrong property name, thus the value not being set.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get a `TypeError` with the arguments to `property` reversed as shown. Corrected to `property(get_value, set_value)`, the code works as expected.

Comment: If you are using `@property` as a decorator, then *both* functions need to have the same name, as you want `value` to be bound to the object returned by `@propety` and `@value.setter`.